# Excel Validation: Rejecting entries in a column that are duplicates or not from a named range

Tags: excel, validation, duplicates

If have the named range "Ref" that contains the values:
 A-100

A-101

A-102

A-103

etc.

How could I set up data validation such that I can use any numbers from "Ref" but not allow any duplicate entries in that column? On a separate sheet for example in which the data validation would apply:

A-103

A-101

A-102

...would be valid but:

A-102

A-102

A-103

...would not be valid (duplication of A-102), and:

B-123

A-101

A-102

...would be rejected on the basis of B-123 not being in the named range "Ref".

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer below link to prevent duplicate values in the range.

http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/prevent-duplicate-entries.html

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response - how would one combine this with only entries from a list?

Comment: If this help please mark as answer so that everyone can get the help

Comment: Hi Mohit - it doesn't address the full question as I highlighted above.

Comment: @user3394391 you need to check both condition something like this in your data validation provided in the above link.  =OR(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$20,A2)=1,COUNTIF(ref,value)>0)=TRUE